# Using jQuery to set the CSS of an element using one of that elements own CSS properties?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a standard style to all javascript scripted hyperlinks in my webapps. Replacing the standard solid line with a dotted line. This can be achieved with CSS however there is a major drawback to that, the border color doesn't match the link color. I figured since the links are using JS anyways, why not do it with JS. Here is what I'm trying to do in jQuery.

```
$(function(){
    $('a.scripted').css({
        'text-decoration': 'none',
        'border-bottom': '1px dotted',
        'border-color': $(this).css('color'),
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't work. $(this) doesn't refer to the selected element and that makes sense. My question is, how can I do this? I tried wrapping it like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('a.scripted').ready(function(){
        $(this).css({
        'text-decoration': 'none',
        'border-bottom': '1px dotted',
        'border-color': $(this).css('color'),
        });
    });
});
```

This also did not work. Advice?

**EDIT**

This code works but not for visited links. I know about the jQuery selector `:visited` but how do I use that in this context?

```
$(function(){
    $('a.scripted').each(function(){

        var $this = $(this);

        $this.css({
            'text-decoration': 'none',
            'border-bottom': '2px dotted',
            'border-color': $this.css('color'),
        });

        $this.hover(
            function()
            {
                $this.css({
                    'text-decoration': 'none',
                    'border-bottom': '1px dotted',
                    'border-color': $this.css('color'),
                });
            },
            function()
            {
                $this.css({
                    'text-decoration': 'none',
                    'border-bottom': '1px dotted',
                    'border-color': $this.css('color'),
                });
            }
        );

        $this.click(function(){
            $this.css({
                'text-decoration': 'none',
                'border-bottom': '1px dotted',
                'border-color': $this.css('color'),
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use each, then $(this) inside to give you a reference to the element being iterated over.

```
$(function(){
    $('a.scripted').each( function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css({
           'text-decoration': 'none',
           'border-bottom': '1px dotted',
           'border-color': $this.css('color')
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the each method.

```
$('a.scripted').each(function () {
    $(this).css({
        'text-decoration': 'none',
        'border-bottom': '1px dotted',
        'border-color': $(this).css('color'),
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('a.scripted').css({
        'text-decoration': 'none',
        'border-bottom': '1px dotted ',
    });
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/qERuL/5/

Comment: in this instance, $(this) wouldn't be the a tag, so you wouldn't get the correct value.  But you could instead say $('a.scripted').css('color')

Comment: Try the jsfiddle link i posted

Comment: this doesn't work.  Notice that the `$(this).css('color')` is evaluated in the scope of the containing anonymous function.

Comment: @Hussein: The javascript in your jsfiddle isn't getting run. You're missing a space after 'dotted', and in jQuery you need to reference css attributes with `textDecoration` and `borderBottom` rather than using hyphens. Even if you fixed those, Jaime was right: `this` is still `window`, and does not have css properties.

Comment: What doesn't work. Border is inheriting link color. Did you check http://jsfiddle.net/qERuL/1. You have blue and red border

Comment: not specifying a border color at all also seems to inherent text color. Check updated answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, jsfiddle has been slow for me today -- it was taking something like 20 seconds to get around to running the javascript. So, you're right, and I didn't know that border-color would inherit from the text color. Cool :)

Comment: No problem. I wish people would comment after testing and not comment based on assumptions.

Answer (score -1):

You really ought to do it with css, if at all possible. Wherever you set your link colors, also set the bottom color of scripted links. If you have multiple places where these links could appear (with different colors for each place), write an `a.scripted` block for each of them.

```
a {
  color: blue; /* or whatever color you like */
}
a.scripted {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  border-color: blue; /* same as above */
}
```